# FREE SELECTIONS not getting Passed to SUBMIT Report FAGLL03

Tags: range, submit, abap, alv, sap-selection-screens

I am submitting the report "FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL" from a custom report on alv_user_command. From my report, I am unable to pass the FAGLL03 free selections.

```
trange_line-tablename = 'ACDOCA_FS'.
trange_frange_t_line-fieldname = 'RMVCT'.
trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line-sign   = 'I'.
trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line-option = 'EQ'.
trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line-low    = 'Z20'.
APPEND trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line
  TO trange_frange_t_line-selopt_t.

APPEND trange_frange_t_line TO trange_line-frange_t.
APPEND trange_line TO trange.

CALL FUNCTION 'FREE_SELECTIONS_RANGE_2_EX'
  EXPORTING
    field_ranges = trange
  IMPORTING
    expressions  = lt_texpr.

SUBMIT fagl_account_items_gl
             VIA SELECTION-SCREEN
       WITH SELECTION-TABLE lt_rspar
       WITH x_opsel EQ abap_false
       WITH x_aisel EQ abap_true
       WITH FREE SELECTIONS lt_texpr
       AND RETURN.
```

Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: so I checked fagl_account_items_gl uses a logical DB:   SDF.
So in theory it should be ok.

Comment: As a side note. Logical DBs are seriously old school. Rarely used any more. 
The Logical DB SDF was created in 1992. Last changed in 2003.  The report fagl_account_items_gl that uses the LDB was added in 2009.  But given the nature of the report. Why not....

Comment: nothing obvious wrong with the code. I built a similar test program to confirm its an issue on current level systems. Suncatcher is very likely right, this is a SAP bug, and you should apply a note. Or notes. Did you try the note they suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Check SAP Note [2391686 - FAGLL03: custom selections doesn't work or error MSITEM103 occurs](https://me.sap.com/notes/0002391686), very likely your S4H system might be affected by this issue as well.

I check on my system, though it is not S4HANA it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Reworked after feedback from **Suncather**.

**You can leave the Parameters SELECTION-TABLE lt_rspar blank

and still include `with selection-table` in the submit statement.**

Thats is not why the free selections are ignored.
The test program below suffers from the same type of problem and confirms the issue you report.
It does look like a free parameter transfer isnt working as expected.

Suggested Solution. See Suncatcher Post.

The test program,

```
  Report ZZSELTEST.
     DATA: lt_rspar TYPE TABLE OF rsparams,
          rspar_line LIKE LINE OF lt_rspar,
          lt_texpr TYPE rsds_texpr,
          trange TYPE rsds_trange ,
          trange_line type rsds_range ,
          trange_frange_t_line type rsds_frange ,
          trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line type rsdsselopt .

rspar_line-selname = 'SD_SAKNR'.
rspar_line-low = '*6*'.
rspar_line-option = 'CP'.
rspar_line-sign = 'I'.
APPEND rspar_line to lt_rspar.

trange_line-tablename = 'BSIS_FS'.
trange_frange_t_line-fieldname = 'BLART'.
trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line-sign   = 'I'.
trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line-option = 'EQ'.
trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line-low    = 'SA'.
APPEND trange_frange_t_selopt_t_line
  TO trange_frange_t_line-selopt_t.

APPEND trange_frange_t_line TO trange_line-frange_t.
APPEND trange_line TO trange.

CALL FUNCTION 'FREE_SELECTIONS_RANGE_2_EX'
  EXPORTING
    field_ranges = trange
  IMPORTING
    expressions  = lt_texpr.



SUBMIT fagl_account_items_gl
             VIA SELECTION-SCREEN
       WITH SELECTION-TABLE lt_rspar
       WITH x_opsel EQ abap_false
       WITH x_aisel EQ abap_true
       WITH FREE SELECTIONS lt_texpr
       AND RETURN.
```

Comment: no, it's not true. One can perfectly use free selections together with SELECTION-TABLE parameter, they are not mutually-exclusive

Comment: yes you can use them together. Good point.  ill fix that.